# Getting Error COMM PCT NOT VALID WITH PU* in sabre EnhancedAirBookRQ

Tags: java, api, sabre

i am getting this error  **COMM PCT NOT VALID WITH PU* - USE COMM AMT-2029** 

when i call EnhancedairbookRQ of sabre

this is my response

```
<EnhancedAirBookRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" Version="2.3.0">
    <stl:ApplicationResults xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" status="Incomplete">
        <stl:Success timeStamp="2017-09-30T00:24:43.017-05:00">
            <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:Element>IgnoreBefore</stl:Element>
            </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Success>
        <stl:Success timeStamp="2017-09-
   30T00:24:43.077-05:00">
            <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:Element>OTA_AirBookRQ</stl:Element>
            </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Success>
        <stl:Success timeStamp="2017-09-30T00:24:53.132-05:00">
            <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:Element>HaltOnStatusRedisplayReservation[1]</stl:Element>
            </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Success>
        <stl:Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2017-09-30T00:24:53.436-05:00">
            <stl:SystemSpecificResults>
                <stl:Message code="0">COMM PCT NOT VALID WITH PU* - USE COMM AMT-2029
                </stl:Message>
                <stl:Message>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</stl:Message>
                <stl:ShortText>ERR.SWS.ORCH.PROVIDER_ERROR</stl:ShortText>
                <stl:Element>OTA_AirPriceRQ</stl:Element>
            </stl:SystemSpecificResults>
        </stl:Error>
    </stl:ApplicationResults>
    .............
</EnhancedAirBookRS>
```

what i do now?

Comment: Can you share the request?

Comment: Have you tried setting the Commission rate when sending the request? Seems like there is a way to set that in the schema:

<xs:element name="Commission" minOccurs="0">

Comment: yes i want to set a commission amount to 5

Answer (score 0):

You can't claim a percentage commission on a PU* fare. Must be set to a flat rate, generally the same as the PU* amount